# C2664: Cannot convert '_Ty' to 'std::shared_ptr'

Tags: multithreading, qt, c++17, visual-studio-2019, smart-pointers

I am trying to pass a `std::shared_ptr` to the constructor of a class and I am getting an error.

I have a struct `PlotterData` defined in a namespace in a separate file:

```
namespace PWN
{
    struct PlotterData
    {
        QMutex taskLock;
        QQueue<PlotterTask> taskQ;
    };
}
```

This struct is accessed by the main class `PlotWidget` which runs in the main thread and `Plotter` class which runs in a separate thread.

plotwidget.h

```
...
std::shared_ptr<PWN::DS::PlotterData> PD;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Plotter>> plotters;
```

plotwidget.cpp

```
...
void PlotWidget::addNewPlotter()
{
    plotters.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Plotter>(new Plotter(PD)));
    plotters.back()->start();
}
```

plotter.h

```
class Plotter : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Plotter(std::shared_ptr<PWN::PlotterData>& pd, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Plotter();

private:
    std::shared_ptr<PWN::DS::PlotterData> PD;
};
```

plotter.cpp

```
Plotter::Plotter(std::shared_ptr<PWN::PlotterData>& pd, QObject *parent)
    : PD(pd), QThread (parent)
{
}
```

When I try to create a new `Plotter` class object I get the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C2664   'Plotter::Plotter(std::shared_ptr<PWN::PlotterData> &,QObject *)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'std::shared_ptr<PWN::PlotterData> &'

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 with Qt plug-in. My C++ version is C++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `std::make_unique` wrong. The argument to `std::make_unique` is passed to the constructor and it calls new internally. You should use `std::make_unique<Plotter>(PD)`